# Is there any way to assign matrix views instead of copying matrices themselves in Matlab, like in NumPy?

Tags: matlab, memory, numpy, matrix

```
A = B(1, :)
```

.. copies the first row of B to A.

Is there anyway to create a matrix view object, something like

```
frB = view(B(1, :))
```

to be able to refere to a view of a matrix ? Also, this would make it so

```
B(1, 3) = 123123;     % set B(1, 3) to 123123 for illustration purposes
frB(3) = 9999;        % set B(1, 3) to 9999
disp(B(1, 3));        % prints 9999
```

See this NumPy example which does exactly that:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pointers in Matlab to point to the same matrix without making a copy. Here's a simple example based on code from [Using pointers in Matlab](http://www.matlabtips.com/how-to-point-at-in-matlab/)

First you define a class that inherits from the `handle` class, which is Matlab's pointer class. The class properties will store your matrix.

```
classdef HandleObject < handle
   properties
      Object=[]; % This will be your matrix
   end

   methods
      function obj=HandleObject(receivedObject) %This is the constructor
         obj.Object=receivedObject;
      end
   end
end
```

To declare your matrix and your matrix view, you do the following

```
M = HandleObject(ones(5,5)); %The constructor passes the matrix to the Object property
M_view = M; %M_view is a copy of the pointer

M.Object(1,1) = 5; %Change the matrix by changing the Object property 

display(M_view.Object(1,1)) %This should display 5
```

You could add more functions to the `HandleObject` to correspond to your desired views.

Comment: it's surprising to me that a HandleMatrix class is not a default object in Matlab.. but I guess it's done to keep things easier to understand to less programming oriented users